# rsync: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(254) [sender=3.1.2]

Tags: ssh, rsync

To establish a backup between a local file server and a remote webspace (with ssh and rsync access) I wanted to use rsync.

With the command

```
rsync -aPv -e "ssh -vv IonosSB" --delete /volume1/fff/sss/ u12345678@home123456789.hostdomain.host:aaa/fff/sss
```

I receive the error message:

```
...
bash: home123456789.hostdomain.host: command not found
debug2: channel 0: written 55 to efd 6
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2604, received 2936 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 36892.2, received 41595.8
debug1: Exit status 127
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(254) [sender=3.1.2]
```

The file `~/.ssh/config` has the following content:

```
Host IonosSB
    HostName home123456789.hostdomain.host
    User u12345678
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /volume1/Data/System/keys/abcdef.key
```

This works fine with ssh, entering `ssh IonosSB` successfully initiates a session on the remote server without entering password.

Manual usage of rsync also works fine:

```
rsync -aPv --delete /volume1/fff/sss/ u12345678@home123456789.hostdomain.host:aaa/fff/sss
```

successfully runs the synchronization after manually entering the password.

So

- ssh works with config definition using certificate and not asking for
  password
- rsync works without ssh config using manual password input
- rsync fails using ssh config with certificate

So far, I have no clue where to look to find reason and cure.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Additional test:

Entering the command

`rsync -aPv -e "ssh -i /volume1/Data/System/keys/abcdef.key" --delete /volume1/fff/sss/ u12345678@home123456789.hostdomain.host:aaa/fff/sss`

worked well without error messages.

So what is different:

entering the certificate directly via -i option or via config file?